# Populate table with D3

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to populate a table with data using D3 but trying to understand how to get this to work. I'm using D3 version 5. Thank you.

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <th></th><th></th><th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For starters I want to populate the th with the object key and populate the td keys value.

// D3 code

```
categories_all = [{"CAT 1":11}, {"CAT 2":12}, {"CAT 3":13}];

const table = d3.select('table');
table.selectAll('th').data(categories_all).enter().text(function(d){
    return d;
});
```

I can iterate using the following pattern with plain javascript but how would this translate to D3?

```
for (let i = 0; i < categories_all.length; i++) {
    for (let key in categories_all[i]) {
        console.log(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you call `enter`, you are given placeholder selection -- the dom elements do not exist. To create, you must call `append` on it

Comment: The dom elements exists and are already there. How do I iterate append the key for each object in the array to each of the th tags?

Comment: Well if you want to update, then don't call `enter`

Comment: As far as finding the sole key -- that's a fairly bad data structure you're going for. I'd rather do it with two arrays -- one array of strings for headers; the other array (rows) of arrays of strings (columns) for data

Comment: Also, creating dom elements yourself is counterproductive; d3's purpose is to eliminate manual dom creation / manipulation

Answer (score 1):

As Coderino Javarino has mentioned, if you're using D3 at all then I'd recommend using it to create the table too.

However, assuming table DOM elements do already exist, then the following should populate the table:

```
categories_all = [{"CAT 1":11}, {"CAT 2":12}, {"CAT 3":13}];

const table = d3.select('table');
table.selectAll('th').data(categories_all).text(function(d){
    return Object.keys(d)[0];
});  

table.selectAll('td').data(categories_all).text(function(d){
    return Object.values(d)[0];
});
```

`enter()` is only required if you're creating new elements.

Even though the above will do the trick, you're probably better off restructuring the data to something like:

```
categories_all = [{key: "CAT 1", value: 11}, {key: "CAT 2", value: 12}, {key: "CAT 3", value: 13}];
```

That way you can access the keys and values as `d.key` and `d.value` respectively.